# CUDA: performance throttling even though clocks are stable

Tags: cuda

I'm doing some benchmarking of a kernel on an RTX 3070 Ti by running it a few thousand times. I've tried to set stable clocks using

```
nvidia-smi -lgc 1575
nvidia-smi -lmc 9251
```

Despite this, I find that performance varies randomly by up to 28%. I've used Nsight Systems to record what happens and sometimes I can see a sharp drop after a few thousand iterations (it's fast and stable until a step transition, after which it is slow and stable). However, I can't see any corresponding dip in clock speeds:

- I've tried just watching `nvidia-smi -q` output (updated every 0.05 seconds) to check for either down-clocking or reports of throttling. Temperature stays below 50°C.
- I've run nsys with `--gpu-metrics-device=0`; it shows the graphics clock stable at 1575 MHz
- I've run the same benchmark using Nsight Compute to record details from every 1000th invocation, which shows that the memory clock is also stable.

I don't have a rigorous test, but it feels like it might be thermal in the sense that performance is worse if I repeat the test immediately after loading the GPU, whereas if I give it a minute to cool off then performance is better.

Any idea what sort of throttling this might be, and how to prevent or at least measure it?

Comment: Launch kernels that have only ```clock()``` - based waiting loops inside. If they don't throttle the same, then its thermal or power. Also keep an eye on memory leaks.